# How to replace value of cell QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I have a column named `foo` and I want to replace certain values from the cells in this column. `foo` is a `string` column.
The values are

```
1, 01, 2, 02, 3, 4, 010, 12, ...
```

I tried

```
replace("foo",'1','01')
```

But this replaces me all the ones `1` with `01`, resulting in

```
01, 0101, 2, 02, 3, 4, 01010, 012, ...
```

I only want completly matching numbers, hence

```
01, 01, 2, 02, 3, 4, 010, 12, ...
```

How to do that?

Comment: How about something like: CASE WHEN "foo" LIKE '1' THEN '01' ELSE "foo" END

Answer (score 1):

You can use function [lpad()](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#lpad): `lpad( "foo", 2,'0')`

From [documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#lpad):

> `lpad()` returns a string padded on the left to the specified width, using a
> fill character.

Answer (score 0):

I did it with

```
case 
when "foo" is '1' then '01' 
else "foo" end
```